# Angular 8 Pipe - Variable is undefined outside Subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, subscription

How can I access a variable inside a subscription in an angular pipe to return the transformed value?

**What I tried**

```
transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {

  const clientKey = args[0];
  let arr = [];
  let newValue;


  this.dbJobs.getJobsFromKey(clientKey).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(jobs => {
    if (jobs && jobs.length) {

      jobs.forEach((job) => {
        arr.push(job.time);
      });
    }
    newValue = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);

    return newValue;
  });

  return newValue;
}
```

the `newValue` variable is undefined in this example. How could I retrieve them to return the new value for the pipe outside this Subscription?

Comment: No, it´s not the solution, because returning the variable inside the subscription will have no effect for the pipe. I need this value outside the subscription to return it..

Comment: What is the effect of `return newValue;` inside the subscription?

Comment: It´s an Angular Pipe (https://angular.io/guide/pipes). I need to change a value with `oldValue | newValuePipe` ... inside the `transform` function I need to return the new value. If I return it inside the subscription, nothing happens.

Comment: Please refer https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-async-pipe/, good post on async pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get asynchronously data as synchronously. It doesn't work that.

In your pipe, you should return Observable value. In this case, you modify your data in `map` Rxjs operator, not in subscribe.

```
transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {

  const clientKey = args[0];
  let arr = [];
  let newValue;


  return this.dbJobs.getJobsFromKey(clientKey)
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      map(jobs => {
    if (jobs && jobs.length) {

      jobs.forEach((job) => {
        arr.push(job.time);
      });
    }
    newValue = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);

    return newValue;
  }));
}
```

And when you want to use this pipe in the template you have to connect it with `AsyncPipe`

For example: `data | yourPipe | async`